# Were children brought to Jesus (Matthew 19:13) because of what he said about divorce, and eunachs (Matthew 19:1-12)?

Tags: matthew

I suppose the core of my question is: in Matthew, is the passage on divorce linked chronologically or thematically. Is there any indication either way -- either the grammar, or comparing it to how these passages were placed in the other gospels.

If these events actually occurred chronologically it might give insight into Jesus ministry, and the attitudes of people at the time. For example, perhaps the people were prompted to bring their children who were the product of adultery, or had some sort of defect from birth.

Or another way to word the question is: was the link between the passages from the people in the story, or from the writer of Matthew?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the main question is no.  The moral of the story is that only with humility can one enter God's kingdom. It is not directly connected to Jesus teaching on divorce and eunuchs. The Pharisees in the earlier part of the chapter tried to "test" Jesus by engaging him in debate about the fine points of the Torah (law). The episode of the little children coming to Jesus provides a powerful contrast to this.

In terms of the placement of this story: Mark agrees with Matthew, but the Gospel of Luke (18:10-14) places it differently, after the parable of the Pharisee and the tax collector. which concludes:

> The tax collector stood off at a distance and would not even raise his
> eyes to heaven but beat his breast and prayed, ‘O God, be merciful to
> me a sinner.’ I tell you, the latter went home justified, not the
> former (the wealthy Pharisee); for everyone who exalts himself will be humbled, and the one
> who humbles himself will be exalted.

Regarding connections, Matthew and Mark's placement emphasizes that entering the Kingdom of Heaven is not a matter of the fine points of the Law. as exemplified by the Pharisees' discussion, but is shown by the trusting attitude of a child. The issue of divorce here is not connected to the story of the children; but the Pharisees' legalistic attitude provides a striking  contrast to child-like trust. In Luke's case, too, the story of the children contrasts to Pharisaic legalism, illustrating the lesson taught by  the humble tax collector's prayer as opposed to that of self-righteous Pharisee.  All three synoptic gospels follow the story of the little children with the episode of a rich man asking Jesus how to attain eternal life.

**Conclusion**: Since Luke arranges the chronology of events differently that Matthew and Mark, it is probable that the authors were inspired to insert a known episode where Jesus said "let the children come unto me" into their narratives in different places, rather than these events occurring chronologically. Both placements emphasize that entry into God's kingdom is a matter of childlike humility, not legalistic conformity.